# Python, multi-processing and memory : how does it work?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm working "for fun" on a dash app that compares execution time of different algorithms.
Here, I want to compare list sorting algorithms, and in this particular case, I'll be talking about the recursive merging algo.

The app works as follows: generate a set of random lists with chosen lengths, chose an algo, run the tests. Using concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor, all lists are sorted at the same time in a different process. I've tried with up to 150 lists and it works fine.

Then, I wanted the merging algo to use 2 processes if the list is bigger than 1024 element, which is also working fine... until I have more than 4 lists. And if I run the test with like 100 lists of length under 1024 and add only one list of a length that will make it use 2 processes to be sorted, it won't work and will return a memory error.

Also, I know about the multiprocessing.cpu_count() function but that doesn't seem to be of any use here? It says I have 12 cpu, but will run 150 processes at the same time and crash for 5 * 2 sub-processes.

So, could anyone explain this to me? I have 32Go of ram and we're talking about 5 lists of 2000 int so...

Edit: Adding the code I used

Each generated list is stored as a Data object:

```
 class Data:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.datas = data
        self.sorted_datas = None
        self.insert_sort_time = None
        self.merge_sort_time = None
        self.mt_merge_sort_time = None
        self.heapify_sort_time = None

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (len(self.datas) < len(other.datas))

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.datas)

    def _sort_by_merging(self):
        a = time.time()
        self.sorted_datas = [item for item in self.datas]
        self.sorted_datas = mergeSort(self.sorted_datas)
        b = time.time() - a
        return b

    def _sort_by_multiprocMerging(self):
        a = time.time()
        self.sorted_datas = [item for item in self.datas]
        self.sorted_datas = multiprocMerging(self.sorted_datas)
        b = time.time() - a
        return b
    ...
```

And all the Data objects are stored in a DataSet object:

```
class DataSet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.raw_datas=[]
        self._datas = []

    def add(self, new_data):
        heapq.heappush(self.raw_datas, new_data)

    def sort(self):
        self._datas = [heapq.heappop(self.raw_datas) for _ in range(len(self.raw_datas))]
        self.raw_datas = self._datas

    def run_tests(self, *algos):
        if 'merge' in algos:
            self.merge_sort_time = 0
            self.merge_datas = []
            with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
                results = [executor.submit(datas._sort_by_merging) for datas in self.raw_datas]
                i = 0
                for result in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
                    self.merge_datas.append((len(self.raw_datas[i].datas), result.result()))
                    self.raw_datas[i].merge_sort_time = self.merge_datas[i][1] * 1000
                    self.merge_sort_time += self.raw_datas[i].merge_sort_time
                    i += 1

        if 'mp_merge' in algos:
            self.mt_merge_sort_time = 0
            self.mt_merge_datas = []
            with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
                results = [executor.submit(datas._sort_by_multiprocMerging) for datas in self.raw_datas]
                i = 0
                for result in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
                    self.mt_merge_datas.append((len(self.raw_datas[i].datas), result.result()))
                    self.raw_datas[i].mt_merge_sort_time = self.mt_merge_datas[i][1] * 1000
                    self.mt_merge_sort_time += self.raw_datas[i].mt_merge_sort_time
                    i += 1
        ...
```

And here are the sorting algos :

```
def mergeSort(my_list):
    if len(my_list) > 1:
        mid = len(my_list) // 2
        left = my_list[:mid]
        right = my_list[mid:]
        mergeSort(left)
        mergeSort(right)
        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 0
        while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
            if left[i] < right[j]:
                my_list[k] = left[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                my_list[k] = right[j]
                j += 1
            k += 1
        while i < len(left):
            my_list[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
        while j < len(right):
            my_list[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1
    return my_list

def multiprocMerging(my_list):
    if len(my_list) > 1024:
        mid = len(my_list) // 2
        left = my_list[:mid]
        right = my_list[mid:]
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            results = executor.map(mergeSort, [left, right])
        sides = [result for result in results]
        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 0
        while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
            if sides[0][i] < sides[1][j]:
                my_list[k] = sides[0][i]
                i += 1
            else:
                my_list[k] = sides[1][j]
                j += 1
            k += 1
        while i < len(sides[0]):
            my_list[k] = sides[0][i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
        while j < len(sides[1]):
            my_list[k] = sides[1][j]
            j += 1
            k += 1
    else:
        mergeSort(my_list)
    return my_list
```

Edit 2 : here is the console log when the app crashes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Process SpawnProcess-186:5:
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import context
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 6, in <module>
Process SpawnProcess-184:10:
    from . import reduction
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 16, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 233, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 116, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\AlgoWebSite\DashApps\algos\Dunod\list_sorting.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from . import numeric
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 911, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 580, in _compile_bytecode
MemoryError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
  File "D:\Python\lib\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\lib\sre_compile.py", line 291, in _optimize_charset
Traceback (most recent call last):
    from . import context
    import socket
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "D:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 264, in run_path
Traceback (most recent call last):
    charmap[k] = 1
  File "D:\Python\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 7, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
IndexError: bytearray index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    import logging
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
  File "D:\Python\lib\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "D:\Python\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 54, in <module>
Process SpawnProcess-186:6:
    from . import context
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
    import logging
    import multiprocessing.connection
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 21, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
  File "D:\Python\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 54, in <module>
    from . import reduction
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    from . import context
  File "D:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 264, in run_path
    import _multiprocessing
  File "D:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 239, in _get_code_from_file
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "D:\Python\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 233, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
    from . import context
    import multiprocessing.connection
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 6, in <module>
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "D:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 239, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 116, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\AlgoWebSite\DashApps\algos\Dunod\list_sorting.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
MemoryError
    import pickle
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiprocessing: Le fichier de pagination est insuffisant pour terminer cette opération.
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
  File "D:\Python\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 54, in <module>
    import multiprocessing.connection
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from . import _add_newdocs
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 874, in get_code
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 21, in <module>
    import _multiprocessing
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiprocessing: Le fichier de pagination est insuffisant pour terminer cette opération.
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\lib\pickle.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
    from . import reduction
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 15, in <module>
    import pickle
  File "D:\Python\lib\pickle.py", line 37, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import reduction
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 15, in <module>
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    import _multiprocessing
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiprocessing: Le fichier de pagination est insuffisant pour terminer cette opération.
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 874, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 973, in get_data
MemoryError
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 973, in get_data
Internal Server Error: /django_plotly_dash/app/lists/_dash-update-component
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 239, in _process_worker
    r = call_item.fn(*call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\AlgoWebSite\DashApps\toolbox\list_datas.py", line 47, in _sort_by_threadmerging
    self.sorted_datas = multiThreadMerging(self.sorted_datas)
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\AlgoWebSite\DashApps\algos\Dunod\list_sorting.py", line 103, in multiThreadMerging
    sides = [result for result in results]
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\AlgoWebSite\DashApps\algos\Dunod\list_sorting.py", line 103, in <listcomp>
    sides = [result for result in results]
  File "D:\Python\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 484, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
    for element in iterable:
  File "D:\Python\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 611, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "D:\Python\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "D:\Python\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\venv\lib\site-packages\django_plotly_dash\views.py", line 74, in update
    return _update(request, ident, stateless, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\venv\lib\site-packages\django_plotly_dash\views.py", line 93, in _update
    resp = view_func()
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\venv\lib\site-packages\django_plotly_dash\dash_wrapper.py", line 560, in dispatch
    return self.dispatch_with_args(body, argMap=dict())
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\venv\lib\site-packages\django_plotly_dash\dash_wrapper.py", line 647, in dispatch_with_args
    res = self.callback_map[target_id]['callback'](*args, **argMap)
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\venv\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 985, in add_context
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\AlgoWebSite\DashApps\Apps\lists.py", line 382, in mergeTest
    data_set.run_tests('mt_merge')
  File "D:\Projets\Python\Algorithmic\AlgoWebSite\DashApps\toolbox\list_datas.py", line 104, in run_tests
    self.mt_merge_datas.append((len(self.raw_datas[i].datas), result.result()))
  File "D:\Python\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "D:\Python\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
HTTP POST /django_plotly_dash/app/lists/_dash-update-component 500 [1.74, 127.0.0.1:63195]
```

Comment: show some code? we can only really guess at the problem otherwise

Comment: Sure, i'll edit the question right now.

Comment: is this 32 bit python perhaps?

Comment: hm no idon't think so : python -v returns "Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32"

Comment: Also, the "threaded version" of the mergin algo, wich is exactly the same function (except for ThreadPoolExecutor() instead of ProcessPoolExecutor()) is running fine in cases that crash with multi process version. Maybe it can narrow down the problem.